# can't access global variables Run time Error '91' object variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

The names of worksheets are declared in a shared module. I was able to access these variables last week when I ran the code.  For some unknown reason they have become inaccessible from other modules and I get Run time error 91' object variable not set every time I refer to a worksheet by set name:

Shared Module code:

```
Public Const WS_ALLV    As String = "Graph_QC"
Public Const WS_LIST   As String = "GeneList"
Public Const WS_QC     As String = "QC"
Public Const WS_COLON   As String = "COLON"
Public Const WS_LUNG    As String = "LUNG"
Public Const WS_MELA    As String = "MELANOMA"
Public Const WS_ALL     As String = "All"
Public Const WS_IGV     As String = "IGVLinks"
Public Const WS_REP1    As String = "Report_1"
Public Const WS_REP2    As String = "Report_2"
Public Const WS_CMMTS   As String = "Comments"
Public Const WS_ACCESS  As String = "Access"

'wsColon wsLung wsMela wsAll wsIGV wsRep1 wsRep2 wsCmmts wsAccess
Public wsQC             As Worksheet
Public wsColon          As Worksheet
Public wsLung           As Worksheet
Public wsMela           As Worksheet
Public wsAll            As Worksheet
Public wsIGV            As Worksheet
Public wsRep1           As Worksheet
Public wsRep2           As Worksheet
Public wsCmmts          As Worksheet
Public wsAccess         As Worksheet
Public wsAllValues      As Worksheet
Public wsGeneList       As Worksheet



Public Sub setSheets()

    Set wsQC = Worksheets(WS_QC)
    Set wsColon = Worksheets(WS_COLON)
    Set wsLung = Worksheets(WS_LUNG)
    Set wsMela = Worksheets(WS_MELA)
    Set wsAll = Worksheets(WS_ALL)
    Set wsIGV = Worksheets(WS_IGV)
    Set wsRep1 = Worksheets(WS_REP1)
    Set wsRep2 = Worksheets(WS_REP2)
    Set wsCmmts = Worksheets(WS_CMMTS)
    Set wsAccess = Worksheets(WS_ACCESS)
    Set wsAllValues = Worksheets(WS_ALLV)
    Set wsGeneList = Worksheets(WS_LIST)

End Sub
```

I get an error message when I try to access these variable from another module. Please see an example where an error occurs.

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> wsAll.Name And ws.Name <> wsIGV.Name And ws.Name <> wsAccess.Name And ws.Name <> wsCmmts.Name And ws.Name <> wsQC.Name And ws.Name <> wsAllValues.Name And ws.Name <> wsGeneList.Name Then
```

Why is this happening all of the sudden?

Thank you

Comment: Do you call setSheets before trying to access these variables? You probably need to initialise the sheet variables. So either use 1) call setSheets or 2) initialise on workbook_open

Comment: @MacroMarc is right: `setSheets()` needs to be executed when the file opens (on `ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open()`). If you get an error message containing the button "Debug" code execution stops and all variables are released so you'll have to run `ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open()` again or just re-open the file